# How to redirect lua print to a new or existing console window?

Tags: c, winapi, dll, lua, luajit

I have a program that injects both *Luajit* and a custom C-written DLL into an **already running** process. The custom DLL calls *CreateThread* in *DllMain* to run a function that creates a new Lua state and runs a Lua script on the victim process. How can I display the *print* output of the Lua scripts in a new console window or preferably the existing console window of the injector?

The injector is just a Lua script ran through *command line* to luajit.exe. It uses FFI and Windows API to find the victim process and inject the lua51.dll and my custom DLL. Keep in mind I cannot run the victim exe. I'm trying to educate myself on creating cheats for a singleplayer Microsoft Gamepass game.

EDIT (Update 1):

```
AllocConsole();
freopen_s((FILE**)stdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen_s((FILE**)stdin, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);

printf("[+] Console activated!\n");
```

With the above code I see a new console and see the output of C printf done from inside the DLL. But do not see output from *print* in Lua scripts. Oddly enough I do not see output from *ffi.C.printf* either. I know the Lua script is working properly because I do see *ffi.C.MessageBoxA* popups.

Comment: [AllocConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole).

Comment: Using `AllocConsole` and then calling `freopen_s(&std_out, "CONOUT$", "w+", stdout);` I see `printf` output from the DLL code but not `print` from Lua. The lua state and libraries are opened after, if that matters.

Comment: Try to use `AttachConsole` to the process that own the existing console or `ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS`, and don't forget to `FreeConsole` first.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?